# How to toast a message after sending an email?

Tags: java, android

How to toast a message after sending an email? This coding inside onCreate() method and inside email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()...

```
            else
            {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Sending Email");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait! We are sending your message to the support department.");
                loadingBar.show();

                Intent sendEmail = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                sendEmail.setType("plain/text");
                sendEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fypadawiyahjalil@gmail.com"});
                sendEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                sendEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "Name: " + name + '\n' + "Email: " + email + '\n' + "Message: " + '\n' + message);

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send mail..."));
            }
            Toast.makeText(ContactUs.this, "Your message has been sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

As shown image below, the toast message appear with an email pop-up.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: use startActivityForResult() method

Comment: where and how should it put? Can you give me an example @Sunny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send mail..."), 0);
```

**receive the result** inside the same activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode  == 0) { // Activity.RESULT_OK
       Toast.makeText(ContactUs.this, "Your message has been sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, this is not part of the API. It returns once you have pressed send button even if it is not sent

ACTION_SEND does NOT have any output as a result you always get the default value which is RESULT_CANCELED.

Also you can NOT check it with Intent data coming back because it is always null either mail send or discard.